# How to integrate Bpoint payment gateway in node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js. I want to integrate BPOINT payment gateway in my node js project. I have searched but did not get any result . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

CBA BPOINT has a developer portal that documents the API including node js SDK libraries with examples. See https://www.bpoint.com.au/developers/v3/ and select Node JS from the combo box in the top right and then follow your nose.

Answer (score 0):

Trexle is a commercial service that lets you integrate [bpoint with nodejs](https://trexle.com/integrations/bpoint/nodejs/) and other platforms. This should be a starting point https://npm.runkit.com/trexlejs

Comment: While links are helpful, [they are not acceptable answers on their own](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). Include the essential parts and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Can you point me out which sections of the resource should I include in the answer?
I couldn't see how relevant is _a BPoint credentials how to get_ to the original question, however the whole method in the resource is a correct answer.